# CSS Sidebar Menu Background Image Issue

Tags: css, background-image, sidebar

I am trying to duplicate this style of a sidebar menu with the background image, but when I use the same stylesheet code and image, it doesnt span the entire height of the sidebar.

The example: http://demo.ponjoh.com/Simpla-Admin/index.html

The css used (on example site and mine):

```
 #sidebar {
    background: url("../images/bg-sidebar.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 230px;
}
```

On my site, the image only displays in its actual dimensions (230x197) and doesnt fill the sidebar. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who coded that CSS implemented the background image of the sidebar twice. Once in the body and once inside the sidebar.

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #555;
background: #F0F0F0 url('../images/bg-body.gif') top left repeat-y;
    /* sets bg image of sidebar, and #F0F0F0 for the rest */
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Here's what you're missing though:

```
background: url("../images/bg-sidebar.gif") repeat-y top left;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a `bottom: 0;` as well as `position: relative;` to the `#body-wrapper` and activating the `background-repeat`. **But be warned!** This is a very dirty CSS coding method and will probably lead to misunderstandings and failures - still it works.

```
#body-wrapper {
    /* Your code stuff ... */

    position: relative; /* absolute positionings are 'relative' to their first 'position: relative;' parent */
}
#sidebar {
    width: 230px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    background: url("../images/bg-sidebar.gif") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the background image is a repeatable image... change `no-repeat` to `repeat` or vertically `repeat-y`